# How do you install TeamSpeak on Ubuntu that is on a Chromebook using a chroot?

Tags: chromebook, chroot, teamspeak

I am on a Chromebook that I use a chroot for Ubuntu on it and I have been trying to install TeamSpeak 3 on it, but it won't let me install it. Please help me figure out how to install it.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install` and a ton of other commands. I've even made it executable but nothing has worked in my situation on this. I just need help and I don't know if anyone will help with this but worth a shot.

Comment: Please add to your original post: What have you tried (commands...), what were the results / messages / errors you received?

Comment: "but it won't let me install it " why not? we need error messages.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install` what? This command doesn't work on its own, and to my knowledge there is no teamspeak package in the official Ubuntu repositories. See my answer on how to install.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.teamspeak.com/en/downloads/ and download the 64bit Linux client to your PC.

Open a terminal and go to the directory you downloaded the file to.

Change it to be executable using `chmod a+x TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.5.6.run` (be sure to use the actual filename you downloaded).

Execute the installer using `sh ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.5.6.run`. Follow the on-screen instructions.